# Two-dimensional Taylor linearisation

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

I have to perform a first order taylor expansion of a function
$f(\vec{x}) = f(x+u,y+1)$ at the point $\vec{a} =(x,y)$. My solution reads
$$ f(\vec{x}) \approx f(x,y) + \left( 
\begin{matrix}
        x + u - x \\
        y + 1 - y
\end{matrix} 
\right)^\top
\left(
\begin{matrix}
        \partial_{(x+u)} f(x,y) \\
        \partial_{(y+1)} f(x,y)
\end{matrix}
\right)
\\ 
= f(x,y) + \partial_{(x+u)} f(x,y) \cdot u + \partial_{(y+1)} f(x,y)
$$
but the example solution is given by
$$ f(\vec{x}) \approx f(x,y) + \left( 
\begin{matrix}
        x + u - x \\
        y + 1 - y
\end{matrix} 
\right)^\top
\left(
\begin{matrix}
        \partial_{x} f(x,y) \\
        \partial_{y} f(x,y)
\end{matrix}
\right)
\\ 
= f(x,y) + \partial_{x} f(x,y) \cdot u + \partial_{y} f(x,y)
$$
Which is the correct solution ? 
Thanks for your help.

EDIT: I'm sorry. I forgot an important aspect, $u$ denotes a function depend from $x$.

Answer (score 1):

In a Taylor expansion, we have a fixed *base point* at which derivatives are evaluated. Here this fixed point is $(x,y)$. So, any dependency of $u$ upon $x$ is moot, since $x$ itself is fixed.

To form 1st order Taylor expansion:

1. Evaluate the derivative at the *base point*.
2. Multiply them by displacement from the base point.

Result:

$$f(x+u,y+1)\approx f(x,y)+\partial_xf (x,y) u +\partial_y f(x,y)$$

Answer (score 0):

They *both* are correct. Observe that if $z=x+u$ the the chain rule says that $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}=\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial z}=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial z}$ since $z$ depends only on $x$ ($u$ being a constant). So your first partials are the same (though one or the other may be more convenient).

Comment: Thanks a lot, but unfortunately i forgot to mention that $u$ is a function depend from $x$.